# Delete rows in a table based on a table value parameter

Tags: sql-server, delete, table-valued-parameters

I have a table `A` and a user defined table type on which a table value parameter (tvp) `tvpA` is based.  Both have the same column structure except that `tvpA` is not defined with any constraint.

What I'd like to do is to delete rows in `A` that are not in `tvpA` based on one of their field called `ID`.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason this simple correlated delete statement won't do the trick?

```
DELETE A
FROM TABLE_A A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM TVP_A
        WHERE ID = A.ID
        )
```